# Get selected Day from UIDatePicker alert

Tags: swift, uidatepicker

Hi developers im trying to get the date & time from UIDatePicker 
my UIDatePicker in on an alert

```
let myDatePicker: UIDatePicker = UIDatePicker()
        let loc = Locale(identifier: "Es_mx")
        //myDatePicker.timeZone = NSTimeZone.local
        myDatePicker.locale = loc

        let date = myDatePicker.date
        let components = Calendar.current.dateComponents([.hour, .minute, .year, .day, .month], from: date)
        let year = components.year!
        let day = components.day!
        let month = components.month!
        let hour = components.hour!
        let minute = components.minute!
       myDatePicker.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 15, width: 270, height: 200)
       let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n", message: nil, preferredStyle: UIAlertController.Style.alert)
       alertController.view.addSubview(myDatePicker)
       //let somethingAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Ok", style: UIAlertAction.Style.default, handler: nil)
        let somethingAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Ok", style: UIAlertAction.Style.default) { (somethingAction: UIAlertAction!) in
                       print("dia: \(day), mes: \(month), año: \(year), hora: \(hour), minuto: \(minute)")
            }


       let cancelAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: UIAlertAction.Style.cancel, handler: nil)
       alertController.addAction(somethingAction)
       alertController.addAction(cancelAction)
       present(alertController, animated: true, completion:{})


    }
```

**already try**

```
let date = myDatePicker.date
            let components = Calendar.current.dateComponents([.hour, .minute, .year, .day, .month], from: date)
            let year = components.year!
            let day = components.day!
            let month = components.month!
            let hour = components.hour!
            let minute = components.minute!
```

so when the user press **OK** button it prints:

```
print("dia: \(day), mes: \(month), año: \(year), hora: \(hour), minuto: \(minute)")
```

Print shows current day, month, year, hour and minute 
im expect to get what the user selected from UIDatePicker

Comment: I can't understand your question. What is the result you expect and what do you get instead?

Comment: Thanks @Teo already edited my question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You initialize a datePicker and get the date from it immediately. This is the problem.

If you want to get the date from the datePicker at the time OK button pressed, you must do this in your closure. Move `let date = myDatePicker.date` line into your closure, Like so:

```
let somethingAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Ok", style: UIAlertAction.Style.default) { (somethingAction: UIAlertAction!) in
                       let date = self.myDatePicker.date
                       print("dia: \(day), mes: \(month), año: \(year), hora: \(hour), minuto: \(minute)")
            }
```

Comment: thanks myDatePicker.addTarget(self, action: #selector(self.cambio(sender:)), for: .valueChanged) did the trick